# Laravel 5 WhereIn two columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two columns: `average_min` and `average_max`.

If `average_min=2000` and `average_max=7000`, I need to find records where `interval` is between 2000-7000:

```
$q->whereAverage_minAndAverage_max($data['average_min'], $data['average_max']);
```

`whereFooAndBar` does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be entirely a good code, but the problem is solved:)

```
if($data['average_min']){
            $q->where('average_min','<=',$data['average_min']);
            $q->where('average_max','>',$data['average_min']);
        }

        if($data['average_max']){
            $q->where('average_min','<=',$data['average_max']);
            $q->where('average_max','>=',$data['average_max']);
        }
```